# Usage of wake desu

Tags: grammar

```
いま しごとを かたづけて しまえば あすは らくが できる **というわけ** です


わけです is used to state the reason of an incident.
```

However,in this case it seems to be different.

Can someone help clarifying the above use of `というわけ`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「[今]{いま}、[仕事]{しごと}を[片付]{かたづ}けてしまえば、[明日]{あす}は[楽]{らく}ができるという**わけ**です。」

In this context, 「わけ」 is used to say that as a result of Action A, Situation B will naturally occur.

Action A: 今、仕事を片付けてしまう (finish one's work now)

Situation B: 明日は楽ができる　(one could relax a bit tomorrow)

Comment: Is there any difference between わけです and というわけです.Could we say '明日あすは楽らくができるわけです' as well?

Answer (score 0):

That expression is something like "the point of the scheme is ...", and it's still a kind of reason for what they are doing.